# Why does this throw a PK duplicate error?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Here is my test case, I hope it's self explanatory.

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task ShouldAllowEntityUpdate()
    {

        var _tenantRepo = LocalIocManager.Resolve<IRepository<Tenant>>();

        Tenant tenant = _tenantRepo.Insert(new Tenant("Tname", "name"));

        var _userRepo = LocalIocManager.Resolve<IRepository<User,long>>();

        _userRepo.Insert(new User()
        {
            Tenant = tenant,
            Name = "jojo"
        });

    }
```

This throws an error because it tries to create a new tenant (again) during the `_userRepo.Insert`. It's this supposed to be tracked by EF, and thus know that it is an existing entity?

A copy of a quick repo is here:
https://github.com/Worthy7/AspAbpSpa/commit/d40f238480934a472a122d6ca6f5cda7ed8e21cd

```
Test Name:  AspAbpSPAMay.Tests.PkDupBug.ShouldAllowEntityUpdate
Test FullName:  AspAbpSPAMay.Tests.PkDupBug.ShouldAllowEntityUpdate
Test Source:    C:\Users\Ian\Source\Repos\AspAbpSPAMay\4.6.0\test\AspAbpSPAMay.Tests\PkDupBug.cs : line 13
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:04.126

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IReadOnlyList`1 entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpDbContext.SaveChanges() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpDbContext.cs:line 208
   at Abp.Zero.EntityFrameworkCore.AbpZeroCommonDbContext`3.SaveChanges() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore\Zero\EntityFrameworkCore\AbpZeroCommonDbContext.cs:line 159
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.SaveChangesInDbContext(DbContext dbContext) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 163
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.SaveChanges() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 60
   at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.CompleteUow() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Uow\EfCoreUnitOfWork.cs:line 77
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkBase.Complete() in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkBase.cs:line 256
   at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformSyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options) in D:\Github\aspnetboilerplate\src\Abp\Domain\Uow\UnitOfWorkInterceptor.cs:line 68
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IRepository`2Proxy_4.InsertOrUpdate(User entity)
   at AspAbpSPAMay.Tests.PkDupBug.ShouldAllowEntityUpdate() in C:\Users\Ian\Source\Repos\AspAbpSPAMay\4.6.0\test\AspAbpSPAMay.Tests\PkDupBug.cs:line 23
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
Result Message: System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 2
```

If this is the wrong way to do this, what's the correct way?

Looking at the [answer on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721538/violation-of-primary-key-entity-framework-code-first) it seems my tenant entity is getting detached for some reason. Is it because it needs to be in an UOW to keep tracking?

Comment: Can you share your table definition in SQL? (Script Table As/Create)

Comment: Could be a limitation of `InMemoryStore`. Do you encounter this in your actual application?

Comment: Yea of course, that's why I wrote the test. I admit the error text itself is slightly different but the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct version:

```cs
[Fact]
    public async Task ShouldAllowEntityUpdate()
    {
        var unitOfWorkManager = Resolve<IUnitOfWorkManager>();

        var _tenantRepo = LocalIocManager.Resolve<IRepository<Tenant>>();

        Tenant tenant = _tenantRepo.Insert(new Tenant("Tname", "name"));

//COMMIT CHANGES to GET the new tenant's Id
_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChanges();

        var _userRepo = LocalIocManager.Resolve<IRepository<User,long>>();

//Use TenantId to set the tenant.
        _userRepo.Insert(new User()
        {
            TenantId = tenant.Id,
            Name = "jojo"
        });

    }
```

Comment: In the end it was down to the UoW not saving the changes. So ending the UoW and starting a new one saw the new change.